# Upload a file chunk without file descriptor using Dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to do chunk upload on Dropbox using Python. My problem is that I don't necessary have access to the file, I can't always get a file handler.

I always have a string containing the chunk I need to upload. But the problem is that `client.upload_chunk` requires a file like object, and I don't understand how the `/chunked_upload` on the HTTP API works. How do you precise the filename?

Here is how I do it right now:

```
e, upload_id = self.client.upload_chunk(chunk, len(chunk), offset)
print "Uploaded: ", e, " upload_id: ", upload_id
```

This does not raise any error and print the size and upload_id but nothing appears on my dropbox.

What is happening? Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: The low-level API has `upload_chunk()` but seems to be missing `commit_chunked_upload()`.  Looking at the `ChunkedUploader` source code might help (e.g. https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/sourcegraph/dropbox/symbols/python/dropbox/client/DropboxClient/ChunkedUploader )

Comment: I think I can use `client.upload_chunk()` my problem beeing how do you precise the filename?? Because this line does what I want `self.client.upload_chunk(StringIO(self.last_block), next_chunk_size, self.offset, self.upload_id)` but still how do precise which file you are updating?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#ChunkedUploader : you give the file name in the `finish()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use `ChunkedUploader` and pass in a `StringIO`.